# How to replace the string

Tags: java, regex, string, str-replace

```
String htmlString ="<font color='#00ff00' size='100'> SampleText </font>"
```

this is a sample `String` where I need to change the font size from 100 to 25. I mean `original font size / 4`.

Is there any solution for the above problem?

The resulting string should be: `"<font color='#00ff00' size='25'> SampleText </font>"`

i think is it posible to do with regular expresion so here i am adding regular expression tag also
htmlString.replaceAll(regularExpression, regularExpression);

Comment: Why C tag? Just because of the word *string*?

Comment: Please explain your problem a little more clearly. Do you want to parse the original string for the font and divide it by 4? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using Java or C? You have tagged both, but I'm sure that's not the case...

Comment: @Duncan i need the java logic

Comment: I think the best way to do it is with regular expression.

Comment: You get a down-vote from me. Absolutely no evidence that you've tried to solve this problem yourself. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Are we all really skipping the fact that he's using the `font` markup with `color` and `size` attributes?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre yes i am using the font tag to display the text.my problem is i am displaying text in mobile but font values are so big thats why i am planning reduce the font size..

Comment: @Arlaud Pierre why not regex? Am I missing something?

Comment: [Yes you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) @wm1sr ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Regular Expression works better.

```
private static String setSize(String htmlString) {
    String reg = "size='[0-9]+'";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String sizeString = matcher.group();
        pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
        Matcher numMatcher = pattern.matcher(sizeString);
        if (numMatcher.find()) {
            String size = numMatcher.group();
            int realSize = Integer.parseInt(size);
            int resultSize = realSize / 4;
            String resultSizeString = "size='" + resultSize + "'";
            htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll(sizeString, resultSizeString);

        }
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: thanks ur code is working and one more question `String htmlString ="<font color='#00ff00' size='100'> SampleText </font> <font color='#00ff00' size='200'> SampleText </font>";` how to replace the size in all places

Comment: What about `<font color="#00FF00">size=10</font>`?

Comment: I had modified the answer which can replace the size in all places. You can try the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your string in two variables `font_size`and `html_template`and use the `sprintf`function to "compile" your template with the values you want as follow :

```
char* html_template = "<font color='#00ff00' size='%d'> SampleText </font>";
int font_size = superFontSizeCalculation();
char* compiled_html = malloc(strlen(html_template));

sprintf(compiled_html, html_template, font_size);
```

I don't check any return of the str* functions but in real usage, you should do it.

Edit : As you changed your mind and want know java and not C, you can have the same mechanism with a small template engine by putting tags in your template string and compile by replacing the tags by your values.

For example :

```
static final String FONT_SIZE_TAG = "<FONT_SIZE_TAG>";
static final String FONT_COLOR_TAG = "<FONT_COLOR_TAG>";

String htmlString ="<font color='" + FONT_COLOR_TAG + "' size='" + FONT_SIZE_TAG + "'> SampleText </font>";

String compiled = htmlString.replace(FONT_COLOR_TAG, "#00ff00").replace(FONT_SIZE_TAG, String.valueOf(FONT_COLOR_TAG));
```

Comment: Looks like the OP wants a java solution.

Comment: yeah, great to have consistent OPs...

Comment: When in doubt, ask comments before jumping in with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as "is this possible with regex, and if it is, how do I do it?"

The answer is no.

Do **not** use regex to parse or modify html. It doesn't work. It can't mathematically work.

Check: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtmlself-contained-tags)

You will always find a solution that works *most of the time* but fails on other examples. So unless you're okay with your solution being incomplete, regex should *really* not be a solution.

Comment: The problem here is that the OP is simply looking for free code. Sadly [this was supplied to him](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20701563/474189).

Comment: @Duncan I understand your pain. But avoiding regex for this kind of operation is still the right call so I'm glad my answer stands in the record.

Answer (score -1):

```
   String htmlString ="<font color='#00ff00' size='100'> SampleText </font>";
            int pos1=htmlString.indexOf("size='");
            if(pos1!=-1){
                int pos3=pos1+6; /*6 is the length of size=' */
                String tempString=htmlString.substring(pos3, htmlString.length());
                int pos2=tempString.indexOf("'");
                if(pos2!=-1){
                    String sizeString=htmlString.substring(pos3, pos3+pos2);
                    String stringToReplace=htmlString.substring(pos1,pos3+pos2+1);
                    int size=Integer.parseInt(sizeString);
                    int newSize=size/4;
                    String newString="size'"+newSize+"'";                        
                    htmlString=htmlString.replace(stringToReplace, newString);
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks this code works

Comment: @user2065281 - if it works then why minus vote?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP Probably a passing user who doesn't like to see a big block of code posted as an answer without any accompanying prose.